# Product of two Lebesgue measurable set is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ two bounded and Lebesgue measurable sets. I have to show that $A\times B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is measurable and \begin{align*}
\lambda(A \times B) = \lambda (A) \cdot \lambda (B)
\end{align*}
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I tried to show the equality of the measure using the Fubini's Theorem with the indicators function but I'm not sure is the right way and I have no idea how to show that $A \times B$ is measurable.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567276/lambda-nm-a-times-b-lambda-na-cdot-lambda-mb

Comment: @user284331 I have only two measurable and bounded set in $\mathbb{R}$. Is there a way to say that they're also Borel sets?

Comment: It should not be a problem to approximate the measure of a Lebesgue measurable set by a Borel measurable set.

Comment: Of course not all Lebesgue measurable sets are Borel measurable, so do not assume them to be Borel one.

Comment: @user284331 you mean writing e.g. $A = H \setminus N$ where $ H$ is a $G_{\delta}$-set (so Borel) and $N$ negligible set?

Comment: Yes, yes, that goes through.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ bounded is measurable if and only if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $U$ a finite union of intervals such that $m^{\star}(A\Delta U)<\epsilon $. Do this for $B$ too and get $$m^{\star}((A\times B) \Delta (U\times V))< 2M\epsilon $$ Multiplicativity should be easy now, since it works for $U$ and $V$.

Comment: Not sure to have understood the notation; what do you mean with $ A \Delta U$ ?

Comment: @userr777: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Comment: I'm some trouble to get the inequality in your answer... you just used only the properties of the Cartesian product?

Comment: @userr777:I also used that $A$, $B$ are each contained in a segment lf length $M$.

Comment: To the proposer: The first sentence of this Answer is valid $only$ for a bounded set $A\subset \Bbb R.$ But $A\times B=\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}( (A\times B)\cap [-n,n]^2)$ so the main result follows from the result for bounded $A,B$.