# Product of Lebesgue Measure is Lebesgue Measure of Products

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, product-measure

I would like to show the Lebesgue measure $\lambda_{n + m}$ in $\mathbf{R}^{n + m}$ has the product property
$$
\lambda_{n + m}(A \times B) = \lambda_n(A) \cdot \lambda_m(B)
$$
for $A \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbf{R}^n}$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbf{R}^m}$, where $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbf{R}^n}$ is the Borel measurable sets in $\mathbf{R}^n$. I know there are similar questions asked on the platform such as [$ \lambda_{n+m}( A \times B ) = \lambda_n(A) \cdot \lambda_m(B) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567276/lambda-nm-a-times-b-lambda-na-cdot-lambda-mb). However, I am not entirely convince of the proof given in the link.

In particular, in the link the author proved the case the set $\mathcal{D}_I$ is a $\lambda$-system, with $I$ being a bounded rectangle (in fact the proof for this is not so convincing either, it seems like the author proved an identity where $B$ is contained fully in a cube $Q$ first and then used this identity in the case where $B$ is not fully contained in a single cube later).

I do not see how this generalize nicely to the general case $\mathcal{D}_{A}$ with $A \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbf{R}^n}$ mentioned later in the proof. The same logic in the proof given would not have applied when showing the complement. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the following lemma from Klenke's probability book: Lemma 1.42 (Uniqueness by an ∩-closed generator) Let (Ω , A, μ) be a σ-finite
measure space and let E ⊂ A be a π-system that generates A. Assume that there
exist sets Ω1, Ω2,... ∈ E such that ∞
n=1 Ωn = Ω and μ(Ωn) < ∞ for all n ∈ N.
Then μ is uniquely determined by the values μ(E), E ∈ E.

Comment: You can show that the lebesgue measure is equal to the product measure by using the above lemma. In other words, the product measure is the unique measure on the product space with the product property. This is true in general for products of $\sigma$-finite measure spaces.